# How to modify the job page of individual job in hudson?

Tags: hudson

I am working with hudson and trying to modify the job specific page for each job. suppose i have created a job "ABC". After adding the job i go to the job page by clicking on the job name on the main dashboard. There in the side panel i want to add one more option suppose say "ABC option" just below the "configure" option. For that which jelly file should b modified??

Answer (score 1):

Use [Docklinks](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/DocLinks+Plugin) plugin.
My guess is using above plugin is the similar way, what you want to achieve....

Comment: Nope. thats not what i am searching for.
i just want the method to add a button in the SIDEPANEL of a particular job page.
In this case after creating a job ABC then i want a button in the sidepanel in this location: "http://localhost:8080/job/ABC/"
where localhost:8080 is my hudson home page.
thanks in advance